# Script (nobody/nogroup) can't write files to NTFS share - permission denied. Root can write

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab, cifs

I have a simple script that is (trying to) unzip a file to a mounted Windows 2012 share. It is normally launched as a Postfix alias when a new email arrives, but even when I run it as root I get a permission denied error.

The script is doing this:

```
if ( </tmp/*.zip> ){
    unzip '</tmp/*.zip>' => '</mnt/win/#1.txt>'
            or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
}
```

As root I can copy files to /mnt/win without a problem, but when this script is launched by Postfix it fails with permission denied.

/etc/fstab looks like:

```
//srvr1/tmp /mnt/win  cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=iso8859-1,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

ls -ld looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 196608 Jul 15 17:24 /mnt/win
```

Files produced by the script are nobody/nogroup, but I'm not sure how I change the permissions of /mnt/win to allow nobody/nogroup to read/write.

```
chmod -R ugo+RW /mnt/win
```

Also gives permission denied. Is there a way to change permissions in /etc/fstab to allow nobody/nogroup? Or should I be running the script differently?